# can i use multi-attach ebs volume with multiple ec2 in one zone for read and write some shared files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, microservices

i have multiple micro services and all use some local files, now i want to run each micro service on EC2 instance separately and perform file operations

(i found some hints from here :- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html )

so i want to know, is it possible?

if possible, then what should configuration of EC2 ?

if not possible then  how can i archive it?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, yes.

According to documentation, there are some limitations:

1. Your EC2 instances should be in one Availability Zone
2. EBS multi-attach supported only for io1/io2 EBS volume family
3. You should use a file system that's cluster-aware (not EX4, etc...)

In case of microservices communication, best practice is use EFS that can be mounted to your EC2 instances. In case of EFS, you can use share storage between availability zones within VPC that increases availability of your application.

Comment: definitely EFS is best, but it is costly too, so i try to go with EBS multi-attach

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. However, multiple writes at a time might result in corrupted files (been there, done that). You can [install Gluster](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/clustered-storage-simplified-gfs2-on-amazon-ebs-multi-attach-enabled-volumes/) to prevent that.

On the other hand, It's recommend to use EFS instead of EC2 multi attach for this kind of work, just remember to put dump file to EFS to increase iops.

Comment: ok, 
i will try this,
but when one service make 1 file then it will visible in other service, because currently not visible till next restart of  other ec2 instance

Comment: Does EFS support appending to existing files without corrupting them?